# Select no duplicate row

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have data like this:

```
Name        Age
-------------------
HieuDoan    15
LinhNa      16
HieuDoan    20
NamL        17
```

I want to select all row with no duplicate data, the result I need:

```
Name    Age
-------------
LinhNa  16
NamL    17
```

How do I query this? The data source is Redshift.

Thanks all.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your query

Comment: It's very common for 2 person have the same name, what's the biz logic behind your requirement?

Comment: also specify which DBMS you are using

Comment: @ArunVinoth i have no idea for this, i just try DISTINCT but i still keep the first duplicate row

Comment: @tibetty hi, it 's just a sample data :D

Comment: @Hatik I'm getting data from Amazon Redshift

Comment: Did you try provided solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example, not considering the fact that making such query is wrong as Name and age can be same for different people, In Oracle I would do something like this, using window functions

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT A.*, 
            count(name) over (partition by name order by name) as cnt 
     FROM MY_TABLE A) 
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this nested query:

```
select name, age from (select *, count(*) as no from student group by name) where no = 1;
```

The record set returned from my experiment in sqlite3:

```
LinhNa|16
NamL|17
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just select all rows with no duplicate data, Following can be the approach.

```
SELECT name, age from
      (SELECT name, age,
         (SELECT count(*)
          FROM table1 t1
          WHERE t1.name = t2.name
          GROUP BY t1.name) AS c1
       FROM table1 t2) table2
    WHERE c1 = 1;
```

The inner query will return `name`, `age` and `count of names` and the outer query will filter out the names with `count=1`.

Following is the output.

[image]

You can check demo [here](http://rextester.com/CJKYQ69308)